# Magento 2 customer address not showing properly

Tags: magento2, customer-address, magento2-migration-tool

I have done **migration** from M1 to M2 but the **customer addresses** not showing properly. There are some magento variables appearing instead.

Please check below screenshot: [image]

I got stuck with this issue from past few days. Please suggest the best possible solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a workarround

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5873

its about the primary key on eav_attribute_set

Answer (score 0):

I face similar problem recently when I migrated from magetno 1.9.1.0 to 2.3.4, probaply I solved the issue.

The problem is in : ATTRIBUTE_SET_ID_ADDRESS . By default it is 2.
Change the ATTRIBUTE_SET_ID_ADDRESS id according to the databse. For me it was ATTRIBUTE_SET_ID_ADDRESS =3, Hope it works for you.

Override this file: vendor\magento\module-customer\Api\AddressMetadataInterface.php

app/code/[YourVendor]/[ModuleName]/Api/AddressMetadataInterface.php

```
namespace [YourVendor]\[ModuleName]\Api;

/**
 * Interface for retrieval information about customer address attributes metadata.
 * @api
 */
interface AddressMetadataInterface extends \Magento\Customer\Api\AddressMetadataInterface
{
    const ATTRIBUTE_SET_ID_ADDRESS = 2;

    const ENTITY_TYPE_ADDRESS = 'customer_address';

    const DATA_INTERFACE_NAME = 'Magento\Customer\Api\Data\AddressInterface';
}
```

app/code/[vendorname]/[vendorname]Customer/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
      <preference for="Magento\Customer\Api\AddressMetadataInterface" type="[vendorname]\[vendorname]Customer\Api\AddressMetadataInterface" />
</config>
```

[image]

Comment: Changing the core file of Magento is not a standard practice and never recommended.

Comment: Yes said true. The file should be override. I have edited the answer