# Migrated Magento 1 Customer address does not show (shows variables as output instead)

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.5, data-migration-tool, variables

**First off, I have searched for a solution here, and on Github, this has never been answered specifically from what I can see, none of the answered items work.**

Migrated Magento 1 address information does not work in Magento 2.  I also see that people have this issue when running older Magento 2 versions as well.

[image: Image output example]

> [Reference question: Magento 2 versions have this issue, resolve by 'upgrading'](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/238118/address-information-and-customer-address-are-not-showing-in-magento-2)
> *The solutions claim to upgrade Magento 2 ~2.2, but I already run Magento 2.3.5 which means I should have the 'fixes applied' already*.

I already have Magento 2.3.5 so this is related to **migrated data rather than an older version issue**

> [Reference question: Magento 2 Customer address not showing properly](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/192510/magento-2-customer-address-not-showing-properly)
> The solution here is viable: by creating a new module (overriding `AddressMetadataInterface`) and **changing a constant ATTRIBUTE_SET_ID_ADDRESS**.

However, I personally feel that fixes for *Magento 1 **migrated data** to 'work' to Magento 2* should not relate to overriding any Magento 2 files - **overriding are for when Magento 2 works perfectly as it should**. I have to create a `MyVendor_Magento1FixesModule` which feels strange.
*While this might be a solution, its a 'hacky solution' that could get lost on new migrations. Changing a **CONSTANT by changing a constant value doesn't feel right either*.*

Besides, I even found code that does this : `'entity_type_id' => 2'` **instead of ** `'entity_type_id' => AddressMetadataInterface::ATTRIBUTE_SET_ID_ADDRESS`, so I really do not understand why constants aren't used everywhere.

**(Imagine starting a new migration for another project with the default core Magento 2 installation files, without this module)**.   **If possible, I want users to advise on database related fixes rather.**

I would rather want to fix these Magento 1 migrated database issues directly inside the Magento 2 database, even if it might be more complicated.

The closest solution is discussed on [Github Magento issue 5873](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5873#issuecomment-522506355), but discusses it from the point of view of deleting migrated attribute sets - which are already tied to data I use ('customer_address' entity_type_code for attribute sets used for another module), so I would like to prevent issues with that module.

#### Too much information?

I want users to see I **have done my own research** and *see reason why this is not a duplicate, because there are various reasons described above why I need an alternative*.

#### Question

I am currently investigating the issue by trying to figure out in the database.

For further investigation, I just need some advice either by a direct answer, or alternatively *just information on which **tables** the `customer_address` entity_type_code data depends on*.

Currently, I have `customer_entity`, `customer_address_entity`, `eav_entity_attribute`, `eav_attribute_group`, `eav_attribute_set` which relate to the `customer_address` entity.

Are there any others tables?
(I am already busy trying to join table data to see what I get).

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can export all customers from magento1 and Import in magento2 with Address.
You have to both seprately in magento 2.
1> import customer only
2> import customer address.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I do this exactly?  I used the **Migration Tool** to import everything (data transfer bugs and all).

Comment: export all customer from magento1 though admin export customer functionality. then default import functionality in magento2 for import customer and customer address